How to change color of a static text control in MFC dynamically
I have a simple MFC dialog based application which contains a static text control among other basic controls like check boxes controls and buttons and a edit box control (see photo). I want to be able to change the colour of the static text control dynamically when a user clicks on the GO button. I've borrowed most of the code below from other SO posts.
I've implemented the following WM_CTLCOLOR message handler as follows:
HBRUSH CFileRenamerDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    CWnd* pWndT = pWnd->GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);

    // TODO:  Change any attributes of the DC here
    switch (nCtlColor)
    {
    case CTLCOLOR_STATIC:

        if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_STATIC)
        {
            pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
            //MessageBoxW(L"TEST", L"TESTING", 0);
            return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
        }
    }
    return hbr;
}

void CFileRenamerDlg::OnBnClickedGo()
{
    CWnd* pWnd = this->GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);
    CDC* dc = pWnd->GetDC();
    dc->SetTextColor(RGB(128, 128, 128));
    //COLORREF ref = dc->GetTextColor();

    pWnd->Invalidate(0);
    pWnd->UpdateWindow();
}


The above code does work as the colour of the static text control does change to the colour specified above but when I try the code written within the OnBnClickedGo() handler it does not work. No errors or debug assertion failure of the sort. How can I change the colour of the static text to anything else ?

You need to invalidate or redraw the static control so it repaints itself.  That doesn't happen automatically just because you change the color.  You also may need to redraw the window behind the static control.

@MarkRansom thank you could you provide some example code or provide a link that might help me code redrawing the static control and not the entire dialog box and every control on it ?

[SOLVED] Just to shed some light as to where the problem lied. I read a post here and here suggesting that the default control ID in resource editor of the static text control should be changed from the default control ID of ID_STATIC to something else such as ID_STATIC_TEXT now all is working. I hope this helps someone else having similar issues. I've posted working code that toggles the color of the static text control.
HBRUSH CFileRenamerDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    
    static int nColor = 0x0;
    int rgbRedC = 0x000000FF;
    int rgbGreenC = 0x0000FF00;
    int rgbBlueC = 0x00FF0000;
    int regbBlackC = 0x00000000;

    // TODO:  Change any attributes of the DC here
    switch (nCtlColor)
    {
    case CTLCOLOR_STATIC:

        if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_STATIC_TEXT)
        {
            if (nColor == regbBlackC) 
            {
                pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 255));
                nColor = rgbBlueC;
            }
            else if (nColor == rgbBlueC)
            {
                pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
                nColor = rgbRedC;
            }
        }
    return hbr;
}

void CFileRenamerDlg::OnBnClickedGo()
{
    CWnd* pWnd = this->GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_TEXT);
    pWnd->Invalidate(0);
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This Q&A explains what IDC_STATIC is and why choosing a different ID makes a particular control uniquely identifiable. That said, the proposed code here differs from the OP's by avoiding to filter on the control ID. You can use any control ID if you never observe it, including IDC_STATIC.

@IInspectable thank you the above code is a cleaner version of the original code. I did forget to add the filter on the control ID. I'll add it to the code now.

Glad to know your problem is solved. You can  click '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer. Just a reminder :)
